Why is no machine learning model capable of predicting my data?
I am working on a project where i need to create a predictive maintenance system that predicts when diesel based generators are going to fail based on features like oil temperature/pressure, coolant temperature/pressure, fuel pressure and RPM. I have tried nearly all machine learning models and they all give me values that never go beyond 65% accuracy and even lower precision scores. I have a pretty large dataset that has 19k+ values, what approach can i follow to make sure i find the correct model ?
I tried working with all readily available models nearly (random forest, KNN, Gradient boosting...).i thought that one of them would eventually yield good results, but i found none of them that had any metrics i could rely on to finish my project
